# MQTT.fx TSLv1.3 SSLContext not available

Tags: mosquitto, tls1.3

Im trying to establisch a mqtt connection to test.mosquitto.org using MQTT.fx.
Im on Windows 10.

Selecting TLSv1.2 as my Protocol works fine.
But using TLSv1.3 the connection fails. "TSLv1.3 SSLContext not available"

Is TLSv1.3 just not jet supported on MQTT.fx?
I could not find anything else regarding that promlem using MQTT.fx.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.7.1, MQTT.fx is bundled with JRE 1.8.0_18.
TLSv1.3 is supported from JDK 8u261 ([source](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html)).
Hence, the used JRE does not support TLSv1.3.

I reported the issue and hope for a quick update.

Comment: would that mean that I could get TLSv1.3 to work if I install the newest JDK. Or do I have to wait for it to get implemented in MQTT.fx ?

Comment: I tried it with Java 15 with the same result. I guess this doesn't work as MQTT.fx runs solely on its bundled JRE. Basically, it's self-contained and not associated in any way with the system-JRE. Hence, you have to wait.
Alternatively, the mosquitto_pub/sub client tools should work with TLSv1.3. http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto_pub-sub-clients/